# How to get the custom post list to admin user edit page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I want to list out some post types in the admin panel admin user section to allow the users to access from the front end.

How can i get the post list in admin user edit profile section?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps that may help you:

1. Use [show_user_profile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/show_user_profile) action to insert a form in User edit page:
2. Use [get_post_types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) function to get a list of registered posts in above form.
3. Finally use [edit_user_profile_update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edit_user_profile_update) action to save your data.

[Here is an example](https://webkul.com/blog/wordpress-custom-fields-user-profile-page/) which shows how to add custom fields to user edit page.

Comment: thanks @Qaisar Feroz for your answer,it helped me.